# vb.net Form flickering black

Tags: vb.net, flicker

The form shows many black boxes, I don't paint any graphics, I also removed the background image and it is still flickering.
I used `double buffer` and used this code below too

```
 Protected Overloads Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or 33554432
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property
```

all this reduced the flickering but it still happens and leaves these black boxes. and it happens when I scroll in a flowpanel too.
I also want to use a background image, so I need something that will work with it too.

Comment: Show us some screenshots.  Also, approximately how many controls do you have in your form(s)?

Comment: the form creates controls according to the user, this may go up to 1200 control

Comment: I assume this is WinForms?  That is WAY too many controls.  Either develop a PAGING system, switch to something that can handle large data like ListView, DataGridView, etc, or change platforms to WPF.

Comment: The `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` (33554432) style enables the `DoubleBuffered` property of every control in the Form. So, you have 1200+ `DoubleBuffered` control in that Form. Maybe you just need to enable the `DoubleBuffered` property of the Form? Besides, and as Mr. @Idle_Mind mentioned, hosting that amount of controls in a single Form is not a good idea. You could replace them with maybe a `DataGridView` or a `ListView`.

Comment: hey, i reduced the controls to only 5 in the form but its still flickering black boxes and lines... what can i do?